# Passing 3d arrays using MPI_Bcast

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran-common-block

I'm trying to pass 3D arrays to all other processes (in FORTRAN 77) using `MPI_Bcast`. `v1` is a common block array. I'm also not sure if I need to broadcast the calculated values of the common array `v1` to all other processes or they will be changed in each processes because of being common. The following is the related piece of code:

```
  parameter (nprocz=48,nzro=1)

    do i=i101,i102
      dist  = 0.015*float(i-iv0)
      adamp = exp(-dist*dist)
      do j = je0, je1-1
      do k = ke0, ke1
        v1(k,j,i) = v1(k,j,i)*adamp
      end do
      end do
    end do

    nmpi01=floor((iv0-ie0-nzro)/(nprocz-1))
    if (mpirank .le. nprocz-2) then
       i101=ie0+(mpirank*nmpi01)
       i102=ie0+(mpirank+1)*nmpi01-1
    else
       i101=ie0+(mpirank*nmpi01)
       i102=iv0-1
    endif

   MPI_Bcast(v1(:,:,i101:i102),(ke1-ke0+1)*(je1-je0)*(i102-i101+1)
 & ,MPI_FLOAT,mpirank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr01)
```

I get the error message:

```
PGFTN-S-0081-Matrix/vector v1 illegal as subprogram argument
```

The sizes of the arrays being passed in are correct. Any comment?

---

I corrected the code and I looped over the ranks and compute all elements of rcount and displs in each rank:

```
integer :: myscount, myi101

do rank = 0, nprocz-1
  nmpi01=floor((iv0-ie0-nzro)/(nprocz-1))
  if (rank .le. nprocz-2) then
    i101=ie0+(rank*nmpi01)
    i102=ie0+(rank+1)*nmpi01-1
  else
    i101=ie0+(rank*nmpi01)
    i102=iv0-1
  endif
  scount=(i102-i101+1)*(je1-je0)*(ke1-ke0+1)
  rcount(rank+1)=scount
  displs(rank+1)=rank*scount+1
  if (rank .eq. mpirank) then
    myscount = scount
    myi101 = i101
 end if
end do

scount = myscount
i101 = myi101

call mpi_allgatherv(...)
```

But still wrong results. 1-in my case, results at each part are used for the next part, especially after `mpi_allgatherv`.so do i need to add `mpi_barrier` after each `mpi_allgatherv`? 2-should mpi_in_place be used? consider i have only one 3d array `v1` that each sub-array `v1(1,1,i)` is calculated by some process and i want to put the calculated subarray in the appropriate part of the same array. 3- i guess i should have `displs(i) = sum(rcount(1:i-1))+1` for i=>2 considering that always displs(1)=1 in fortran77. so i corrected to this: before the loop `displs(1)=1`, inside the loop `displs(rank+2)=rank*scount+1` and after the loop `displs(nprocz+1)=0`. am I right?

Comment: Can you show the smallest complete code sample that demonstrates the problem? Note that I didn't say, copy and paste all of your code into the question as that's way too much for us to parse through. You might find the answer to your problem while you're providing better information.

Comment: wesley i edited my post. thanks for any comment

Comment: What happens if you `CALL MPI_Bcast(...)`?

Comment: @ IRO-bot why call? thats not a subroutine. im trying to remove mpi_bcast to see what happen. the array v1 is a common block array and is global to every process. but still not sure if i calculate some part of this array with each process, the changes in that part will be made in the other processes. what do you think

Comment: Yes, in Fortran, all MPI routines are subroutines. What MPI implementation do you use? `MPI_FLOAT` also looks odd as a data type, see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Derived_Data_Types. In your case, a call to `MPI_Bcast` will send a slice of `v1` from root process, `mpirank`, to all other processes. `v1` must be declared on all processes. See http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.7/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php on how to use `MPI_Bcast`.

Comment: the links are very useful.
i created a library (commons.h) containing all the common blocks including v1 but didnt declare v1 separately in each process. so, still do i need to mpi_bcast the calculated part to all other processes? besides i dont have any root process, i behave all the process the same and the result will be saved in out files after mpi_finalize (err). does this work?

Comment: No, what I mean is, the argument #4 to `MPI_Bcast` is the root process that sends the message, in your case `v1`. All other processes that call `MPI_Bcast` receive the message into their local `v1`.

Comment: please look at my answer to question. my problem not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Fortran 77 was more restrictive about array subscripts than Fortran 90, and pgftn is a Fortran 77 compiler. I would try passing `v1(1,1,i101)` to mpi_bcast, not `v1(:,:,i101:i102)`. (Or use pgf95 with the "-Mfixed" flag.)

If each process needs to see v1, then you do need to communicate it using MPI. No variable is shared between MPI tasks, not even those in a common block. However, if every process is calculating a different part of v1, so every process needs a piece from every other process, you can't use `mpi_bcast` to do that; use `mpi_allgather` instead.

Also, as noted above, when you use MPI procedures, you should `call` them, because they are subroutines.

Comment: @ Sean patrick santos so first i tried this: scount=(i102-i101+1)*(je1-je0)*(ke1-ke0+1) rcount(mpirank+1)=scount  displs(mpirank+1)=mpirank*scount+1          call MPI_ALLGATHERV(v1(1,1,i101),scount,MPI_REAL,v1(1,1,1)
,rcount,displs,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr004)
but i got this error:
Fatal error in PMPI_Allgatherv: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
...
MPIR_Localcopy(378).......: memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x7ccddb44 src=0x7ccddb40 len=3642752

Comment: @ Sean patrick santos then i changed it to: call MPI_ALLGATHERV(MPI_IN_PlACE,scount,MPI_REAL,v1(1,1,1) ,rcount,displs,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr004) but the memory was used incrementally until the program crashed. whats the problem at each case?

Comment: For the first command, the problem is simply that you tried to send and receive in the same buffer; you need `MPI_IN_PLACE` for that. For the second one, the arguments that you have as `rcount` and `displs` must be vectors. Without knowing what you passed, I can't tell you what the problem might be.

Comment: please look at my answer to my question